# Can't get CouchDB rewrite to work

Tags: javascript, database, url-rewriting, couchdb, nosql

Here's my design document:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/posts",
  "_rev": "24-ad9e24a7dd4cabea0a93921ba5c1e5d0",
  "views": {
    "titles": {
      "map": "function( doc ) {\n    if( doc.title ) {\n        \n        emit( doc._id, doc.title );\n        \n    }\n}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript",
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "from": "/",
      "to": "/index.html"
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "from": "/api/recent",
      "to": "/_view/titles"
    }
  ],
  "_attachments": {
    "index.html": {
      "content_type": "text/html",
      "revpos": 20,
      "digest": "md5-5hL6AbwxZ7nV+KF7FDHMTA==",
      "length": 672,
      "stub": true
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my `[vhosts]` entry in `couchdb.ini`:

```
couch.app:1111 /blog/_design/posts/_rewrite
*.couch.app:1111 /blog/_design/posts/_rewrite
```

I've also added `couch.app` to my `hosts` file, and I can ping it and view it in the browser at `http://couch.app:1111`, however I am unable to get the rewrites working. Querying the following URLs produces results as expected:

`http://localhost:1111/blog/_design/posts/index.html` - shows the index attachment
`http://localhost:1111/blog/_design/posts/_view/titles` - shows the `titles` view

But if I go to any of the rewritten URLs, I get some errors:

`http://couch.app:1111/api/recent` - results in:

```
{
error: "not_found",
reason: "no_db_file"
}
```

And `http://couch.app:1111/` just gives me CouchDB welcome message:

```
{
    couchdb: "Welcome",
    uuid: "e53384e83c77b3aa37eb7849838ff8dd",
    version: "1.6.1",
    vendor: {
        version: "1.6.1_3",
        name: "Homebrew"
    }
}
```

I've been struggling with this for the past two days. I've read the entire manual, a few tutorials but haven't actually found a good, working piece of example code. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error until I fixed my [vhosts] entry. It may be just a problem with your post, but it looks like you are missing the '=' in your [vhosts] entries.

Try like this:

```
couch.app:1111 = /blog/_design/posts/_rewrite
*.couch.app:1111 = /blog/_design/posts/_rewrite
```

My problem was that I had not added port 5984. I thought it was not required, being the default. After I added the port, it worked.

Before I added the port, coudhdb.log, with level = debug, did not log a rewrite. After I added the port, it did.